# Solve an issue using algorithm using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

I am working on following example

```
Given: 2 sorted arrays of integers(e.g. A = [1,2,3,4,5], B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) and answer(e.g 13)
Find: What I have to do is to find pair of indices(1 in each array) of those two elements in both arrays so when I add them then it should be equal to the given answer.
```

I used following 2 solutions. But the problem with both of them is that I am looping through both arrays. First I loop through first array and inside this I loop
through second array. And add elements on those two indices to see if its addition is equal to answer. It works fine and outputs correct answer. The problem is 
performance. If we have 10,000 integers in both arrays then these loops will take a lot of resources such as time, CPU and memory to be executed and get answer.

**How can I solve above particular problem in more efficient way?**

```
function find (A1, A2, ans) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0, len1 = A1.length; i < len1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, len2 = A2.length; j < len2; j++) {
      if (ans === A1[i] + A2[j]) {
        a.push(i + ', ' + j);
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

second

```
function search (A, B, ans) {
  var arr = [];
  A.map(function (v, i) {
    B.filter(function (val, ind) {
      if (ans === v + val) arr.push(i + ', ' +ind);
    });
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: What shall happen when no match is found (eg answer = 16 in your example) ?

Comment: Then it should return false/error.

Comment: Iterate first array and use binary search in second. Time complexity will be O(n log m). Your current time Complexity is O(n * m). binary search will save your time.

Comment: How is this a jQuery question?

Comment: @Md.Yusuf It would be O(N log M).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution1**
You can iterate through all elements of array with lesser elements up to answer and binary search in second array for `(answer - array[index])`, complexity of this algo is `O(N log M)`.

[Live code in C++](http://ideone.com/XqESTv)

**Solution2**
Or you can merge both arrays in linear time and apply following algorithm to find the pair in linear time. While merging, keep reverse mapping arrays mapA and mapB of size `N+M` in which mapA[i] points to index in array A from where i<sup>th</sup> array of merged array came and -1 otherwise. Do similar for mapB also.

```
/* Merge the arrays */
mapA, mapB, MA all are arrays of size M+N, initialized with all -1
i = 0, j = 0
while(i < M && j < N)
    if(A[i] < B[j])
        MA[i+j] = A[i];
        mapA[i+j] = i++;
    else
        MA[i+j] = B[j];
        mapB[i+j] = j++;
while(i < M)
    MA[i+j] = A[i];
    mapA[i+j] = i++;
while(j < N)
    MA[i+j] = B[j];
    mapB[i+j] = j++;

/* Search the pair */
i = 0
j = N + M - 1
while(i < j){
   if(mapA[i] == -1) i++;
   else if(mapB[j] == -1) j--;
   else if (MA[i] + MA[j] == answer) return pair(mapA[i], mapB[j]);
   else if (MA[i] + MA[j] <  answer) i++;
   else if (MA[i] + MA[j] >  answer) j--;
}
return null_pair;  // no answer found
```

[Live code example in C++](http://ideone.com/QLE6Qq)

**Solution3**
There is a better algorithm (inspired from 3 sum algorithm) which works in linear time i.e. O(N + M) in constant space.

```
i = 0
j = M - 1
while(i < N && j >= 0){
   if      (A[i] + B[j] == answer) return pair(i, j);
   else if (A[i] + B[j] <  answer) i++;
   else if (A[i] + B[j] >  answer) j--;
}
return null_pair;  // no answer found
```

**Proof**
Let's assume `A[x] + B[y] = answer`. Then either `x` will reach `i` first or `j` will reach `y` first or we will find some other pair such that `A[i] + B[j] = answer`. Without loss of generality let's assume `x` becomes `i` first. Now for all `j > y`, `A[i] + B[j] > answer` so j will eventually reach answer. If there is no answer, we will exit the loop.

Comment: I think you mean O(N log M) for the first approach.

Comment: Also wouldn't it be O(N + M) in linear time?

Comment: Yes if size of smaller array is N. N log N if size of both arrays are comparable. Similary O(N+M) is similar to O(N) in same way. But your point is right, I would update it.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind `while (i < j)`? If you had two arrays `[1, 2, 3]` and `[10, 17]` and you were looking for the sum `13`, the answer would be at `i = 2, j = 0` and your `while` loop would have already exited.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for correction. While porting it from [3sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) algorithm, it was a leftover mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Could you elaborate what are M and N?

Comment: you mean M is the size of Array A and N is the size of Array B or vice versa?

Comment: @26ph19 It can be either. For the first approach, it would be wise to do the binary search on the larger array, in which case N would be the size of the smaller array and M would be the size of the larger array.

Comment: Why that 3rd solution was removed? Could you put it back?

Comment: I have put a O(M+N) solution below.

Answer (score 2):

```
// get all pairs of number from array a and b, that a[i] + b[j] = sum
// return array of pairs
function getSumPairs(a, b, sum) {
    var pa = 0, pb = b.length - 1;
    var pairs = [];
    while (pa < a.length && pb >= 0) {
        if (a[pa] + b[pb] > sum ) {
            pb = pb - 1;
        } else if (a[pa] + b[pb] < sum) {
            pa = pa + 1;
        } else {
            pairs.push([a[pa], b[pb]]);
            pa = pa + 1;
            pb = pb - 1;
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}


// data for test
var arr1 = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9],
    arr2 = [5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15];

console.log(getSumPairs(arr1, arr2, 14))
console.log(getSumPairs(arr1, arr2, 15))
```

The algorithm is to sum the data from array `a` and `b` from different end. As the arrays are sorted:

if `a[i] + b[j] < sum`, `a[i] + b[j-1]` will still less than `sum`, so just need to increase `i`.

if `a[i] + b[j] > sum`, `a[i+1] + b[j]` will still larger than `sum`, so just need to decrease `j`.

Thus, all the elements from the tow arrays are only looped once. The complexity is `O(M + N)`, for a[N] and b[M].

Try for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/9L4p1j3L/

Comment: Hi @MohitJain, for both of your input, I have run the code, and it get [3,9], and [9, 3] respectively. Just change the input and call `getSumPairs(arr1, arr2, 12)`.

Comment: @GreenSu could you create a jsfiddle for this with my inputs in question? It does not work properly for that input.

Comment: I mean it does not work for this input `var arr1 = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -7], arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 11];`. for this one `-7+20=13` but it does not evaluate this as true and does not put in pairs array.

Comment: @26ph19 As the question described, the input should be two `sorted array`. So your input is not valid. `arr1` should be `[-7, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @26ph19 And `arr2` be `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]`

Answer (score 1):

```
function find (A1, A2, ans) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0, len1 = A1.length; i < len1; i++) {
    var noToSearch = ans - A1[i];
    var secondIndex  = binarySearch(A2,noToSearch);
    if(secondIndex !=-1){
        a.push(i + ', ' + secondIndex );
    }
  }
  return a;
}

function binarySearch(A2,num){
 var index = -1;
  //write binary search algo to find the element in array A2
 return index;
}
```